# Applying rules to expressions

Tags: rule

I'm trying to write a rule that acts on any number, lists, expression and so on to turn any negative numbers positive.

The simple `r = n_ -> Abs[n]` works perfectly well for numbers, lists and nested lists, but does not work expressions, such as `Exp[-5]`, which is unaffected by my rule.  I can't use the replace function, because I also require my rule to work for other Mathematica inputs, like numbers, lists and nested lists.

Can someone suggest why this does not work?  Is it due to the rule not penetrating the expression?  An edit to my rule would also be much appreciated.

Comment: I think it is working, but it's working on `Exp[-5]`.  `Trace` shows you the sequence of evaluation steps:  `Trace[Exp[-5] /. r]`.  Perhaps `Exp[-5] /. n_?NumberQ :> Abs[n]` is what you're after?

Comment: @MichaelE2, using your method, why can we get `(-E)^(-5)` to return `E^5`, but we can't get `(-2)^(-5)` to return `2^5`?  Changing the `-2` to `-2.0` doesn't change it either.

Comment: @JasonB Perhaps `Trace` and the observation that `NumberQ[E]` is `False` leads to an explanation.  E.g., `(-2)^(-5)` evaluates to `-1/32` before any rules are applied. See if you can figure out `HoldForm[(-2)^(-5)] /. n_?NumberQ :> Abs[n] // Trace` -- it stumped me at first. `Inactivate[(-2)^(-5)] /. n_?NumberQ :> Abs[n]` is the only way I figured out to do what you want.

Comment: For `Log[1/E]`, do you want to get 1 or -1?  (I.e. do you want `Abs[ Log[ Abs[ Abs[1]/Abs[E]]]]` or only `Log[ Abs[1/E]]`, respectively?)

Comment: This question needs a good size set of example inputs with desired outputs. Too many people are needing too many guesses to sort out what actually is wanted, and that amounts to wasted time.

Answer (score 5):

A few more examples provided at suggestion of OP.

```
Replace[Unevaluated[{Exp[-5], -7, (-2)^(-5), BesselJ[-2, -3], 
    Cos[-5], {-Pi, -E}, Exp[-5 Exp[-5]]}], n_ -> Abs[n], {0, Infinity}]

(* {E^5, 7, 32, BesselJ[2, 3], Cos[5], {π, E}, E^(5 E^5)} *)
```

may be what you want.  (Note:. `Unevaluated` needed to handle `(-2)^(-5)`.)

**Addendum**

This can be written as a function by

```
f = Function[x, Replace[Unevaluated[x], n_ -> Abs[n], {0, Infinity}], HoldAll]
```

Then,

```
f@{Exp[-5], -7, (-2)^(-5), BesselJ[-2, -3], Cos[-5], {-Pi, -E}, Exp[-5 Exp[-5]]}
(* {E^5, 7, 32, BesselJ[2, 3], Cos[5], {π, E}, E^(5 E^5)} *)
```

as before.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I should have made my question clearer (I have just edited it).  I require this rule to work for all kinds of mathematica inputs, such as numbers, lists of numbers, Cos[-5] and so on.  Therefore, Replace won't work since it is far too specific.

Comment: @Pablo  Works for those too.  See addition to list of examples.  The third argument, `Infinity`, causes `Replace` to reach inside functions.  The suggestion by MichaelE2 works well too, of course.

Comment: @bbgodfrey I believe `Reduce[ expr, n_?NumberQ -> Abs[n], Infinity]` might work and be more precise? (Oh, I see that is what MichaelE2 has suggested above)

Comment: @gwr  Certainly, your suggestion works too, but I am not sure what you mean by "more precise".

Comment: @bbgodfrey While testing `?NumberQ` takes time, we will not need to have nested `Abs[ ]` in a nested expression, but that is what we will get without the filtering.

Comment: @bbgodfrey I tried your suggestion in the following form r = m_ -> Replace[{m}, n_ -> Abs[n], Infinity], in an attempt to be able to apply this rule to any function, but unfortunately it doesn't work.  For example, -7/.r = m_ -> Replace[{m}, n_ -> Abs[n], Infinity] simply returns -7.  I don't understand why this won't work, despite the fact than when I plug r = m_ -> Replace[{-7}, n_ -> Abs[n], Infinity] directly it works fine.

Comment: @Pablo That is a `Precedence` issue so you will need `-7 /. ( r = m_ -> ...)`

Comment: I'm sorry @gwr , I don't really understand what you're suggesting.  Even when I wrap brakes around as I think you are suggesting, it does not work `Exp[-5] /. (m_ -> Replace[{m}, n_ :> Abs[n], Infinity])`

Comment: @Pablo  What you are trying is not what I suggested in my answer.  Use `Replace[Unevaluated[list of stuff], n_ -> Abs[n], {0, Infinity}]` to make all parts of `list of stuff` positive.

Comment: @bbgodfrey Unfortunately, for that to work though, I will need to input every single possible combination of lists in to that first argument, which is impossible.  I need to be able to apply some rule that will turn any arbitrary term that contains numbers that are negative into a term that is equivalent to the first, except with positive numbers.  For example, `Exp[-5] /. m_ -> Replace[Unevaluated[m], n_ -> Abs[n], {0, Infinity}]` should output `E^5`, but it does not.

Comment: @Pablo The functional form added to my answer may get closer to your goal. Just prefix f@ to an expression to change all numbers in it to positive.  (In some instances, you may need to enclose the expression in parentheses.)

Answer (score 2):

`Exp[-5]` is not unaffected by your rule at all; on the contrary,

```
Trace[Exp[-5]/.n_->Abs[n]]
```

shows that `Exp[-5]` is replaced by `Abs[Exp[-5]]`, which is equal to `Exp[-5]`. If you only want stuff that "looks like" numbers to get replaced, you can use

```
Replace[Exp[-5],n_->Abs[n]],-1]
```

which replaces anything that does not have a sub-part, i.e. it would give

> e^5

But what about stuff like `(-2)^(-5)`? Do you want to replace both (-2) and (-5)?

Comment: Yes, I want to change every single thing that "looks like" a number from negative to positive before completing the operation.  Thank you for your edit on the Exp[-5] example

Answer (score 2):

In slight modification of @bbgodfrey's excellent answer, what you might use is this:

```
SetAttributes[ f, HoldAll ];
f[ expr_ ] := Replace[
      HoldForm @ expr, (* prevent any evaluation before replacement *)
      n_ -> Abs[n], (* ?NumberQ would not work then *)
      Infinity
    ]//ReleaseHold;


f[ (-2)^(-5) ]
```

> 32

Comment: So you might use `Replace[ HoldForm @ expr, n_?NumberQ -> Abs[n], Infinity]//ReleaseHold`.

Comment: There are subtle differences for `HoldForm` and `Unevaluated` which I have not pondered too far. With `Unevaluated` there is no need for a `ReleaseHold`.